# Custom placeholder for all WooCommerce checkout fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, woocommerce-checkout-fields

I am trying to add a placeholder to my WooCommerce checkout fields, and it's working perfectly for every field **except for the phone and the email** fields.

This is the code I am using:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'override_address_fields');
function override_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['first_name']['placeholder'] = 'Fornavn';
    $address_fields['last_name']['placeholder'] = 'Efternavn';
    $address_fields['address_1']['placeholder'] = 'Adresse';
    $address_fields['state']['placeholder'] = 'Stat';
    $address_fields['postcode']['placeholder'] = 'Postnummer';
    $address_fields['city']['placeholder'] = 'By';
    $address_fields['phone']['placeholder'] = 'Telefon';
    $address_fields['email']['placeholder'] = 'Email';
    return $address_fields;
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Why isn't the phone and email putting out any results?

I have taken the IDs from that two fields using my browser developer tool inspector.

---

**Edit:**

**I have also tried this suggested code:**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'override_checkout_fields');
function override_checkout_fields( $checkout_fields ) {
    $checkout_fields['first_name']['placeholder'] = 'Fornavn';
    $checkout_fields['last_name']['placeholder'] = 'Efternavn';
    $checkout_fields['address_1']['placeholder'] = 'Adresse';
    $checkout_fields['state']['placeholder'] = 'Stat';
    $checkout_fields['postcode']['placeholder'] = 'Postnummer';
    $checkout_fields['city']['placeholder'] = 'By';
    $checkout_fields['phone']['placeholder'] = 'Telefon';
    $checkout_fields['email']['placeholder'] = 'Email';
    return $checkout_fields;
}
```

**And this one too:**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'override_checkout_fields');
function override_checkout_fields( $checkout_fields ) {
    $checkout_fields['billing_first_name']['placeholder'] = 'Fornavn';
    $checkout_fields['billing_last_name']['placeholder'] = 'Efternavn';
    $checkout_fields['billing_address_1']['placeholder'] = 'Adresse';
    $checkout_fields['billing_state']['placeholder'] = 'Stat';
    $checkout_fields['billing_postcode']['placeholder'] = 'Postnummer';
    $checkout_fields['billing_city']['placeholder'] = 'By';
    $checkout_fields['billing_phone']['placeholder'] = 'Telefon';
    $checkout_fields['billing_email']['placeholder'] = 'Email';
    return $checkout_fields;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Hello there, I have a working tested answer regarding your question, please try it. Some feed back on it should be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec great answer, thanks. Now, how to customize the placeholders in the login fields? `$fields['account']['account_username']['placeholder']   = __( 'Email*', 'woocommerce' );`should work with the filter `woocommerce_checkout_fields`...but it doesn't.

Comment: Actually the question has been posted here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340779/woocommerce-add-placeholder-text-to-login-form-user-field  can you give us an answer there ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looking at the [official docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/), you will see that **there is no** `'phone'` and `'email'` key fields for the default addresses when using **`woocommerce_default_address_fields`** filter hook. 
Accepted fields keys are: 
`country`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `company`, `address_1`, `address_2`, `city`, `state`, `postcode`.

This is why you can get changes using **`woocommerce_default_address_fields`**

Email and phone are **billing** fields and they are available trough **`woocommerce_checkout_fields`** filter hook. They are named (see in the documentation) `'billing_phone'` and `'billing_phone'`…

The correct way to override them is:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'override_billing_checkout_fields', 20, 1 );
function override_billing_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['placeholder'] = 'Telefon';
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['placeholder'] = 'Email';
    return $fields;
}
```

And for the others fields (billing and shipping):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'override_default_address_checkout_fields', 20, 1);
function override_default_address_checkout_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['first_name']['placeholder'] = 'Fornavn';
    $address_fields['last_name']['placeholder'] = 'Efternavn';
    $address_fields['address_1']['placeholder'] = 'Adresse';
    $address_fields['state']['placeholder'] = 'Stat';
    $address_fields['postcode']['placeholder'] = 'Postnummer';
    $address_fields['city']['placeholder'] = 'By';
    return $address_fields;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

All code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

---

Reference: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

---

For the login form fields: [Customize WooCommerce login form user fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57340779/customize-woocommerce-login-form-user-fields/63061652#63061652)

Comment: This was the solution! You are amazing, thanks a lot. For everybody with same issues try this out.

Comment: But what you do if you want an addres field like ADDRESS_1 to be required, i cant figure that one out. Where do you put the required point in.

Comment: @amirhanif You might look for `$address_fields['address_1']['required'] = true;` to be placed in the 2nd hooked function (in this answer code).

Comment: There is a mistake in this answer. If you want to replace the email placeholder use $fields['billing']['billing_email']['placeholder'] not  $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['placeholder']

Comment: @Laurent just changed… sorry.

Answer (score 3):

per the official documentation https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/
Here you have the updated code:

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'override_billing_checkout_fields', 20, 1 );
 function override_billing_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

     $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['placeholder'] = 'Prénom';
     $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['placeholder'] = 'Nom';
     $fields['billing']['billing_company']['placeholder'] = 'Nom de la société (optionnel)';
     $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['placeholder'] = 'Code postal';
     $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['placeholder'] = 'Téléphone';
     $fields['billing']['billing_city']['placeholder'] = 'Ville';


     $fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name']['placeholder'] = 'Prénom';
     $fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name']['placeholder'] = 'Nom';
     $fields['shipping']['shipping_company']['placeholder'] = 'Nom de la société (optionnel)';
     $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']['placeholder'] = 'Code postal';
     $fields['shipping']['shipping_phone']['placeholder'] = 'Téléphone';
     $fields['shipping']['shipping_city']['placeholder'] = 'Ville';

     return $fields;
 }
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the [WooCommerce documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) you may want to try using the `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter instead of `woocommerce_default_address_fields`

Seems more logical as the fields above aren't all address related, and that hook derived from `class-wc-countries.php`.

Also, note the field names are different based on the context of the page, for example, the billing page fields are named as so:

- billing_first_name
- billing_last_name
- billing_email
- billing_phone

Hope that helps! Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out! I tried this at first, but then it just adds no placeholders to any of them. Am I doing it wrong? I edited your psot with the code.

Comment: @eMikkelsen I've edited my original answer, that should be it.

Comment: Thank you for still helping out. Just tried the above code as well, and changing these fields adding billing_ does not help either. I have attached the full code in the edit in the top.